# If I am asked to minimize f, subject to several constraints g_i, and I find only one critical point, must this point be where f attains a minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am guessing that it must be, but I feel that I have only found a unique critical point, so that this point could be either a unique absolute max or a unique absolute min -- I say uniqueness because the question states further to show that the minimum of f is unique.

Do I just conclude that this single critical point is exactly my unique absolute min, without having other critical points to evaluate and compare to?  My work included solving a block system of linear equations.

EDIT:  The function is: $\large I(u)=∑_{i,j=1}^nL_{ij}u_iu_j−2∑_{j=1}^nf_ju_j$

with the assumption that $∑_{i,j=1}^n L_{ij}u_iu_j≥0$ and strictly positive for all non-zero $\vec u$.

The constraint is:  $\large ∑_{j=1}^n A_{ij}u_j = g_i$ for i=1,2,…,m.

The Hessian that I computed in the unconstrained optimization part of the question was positive-definite for all critical points, hence all critical points found were minimums of f.  But I do not think that the Hessian is relevant to the constrained optimization part of the problem, for which I have found *one* critical point.

Thanks,

Comment: The answer is clearly no, because if it is, then it would be a maximum for the negative of the function.

Comment: Yes, that was the first part of the question, without the constraints.  The Hessian was positive-definite, for any critical points, so any critical points was a minimum.  I showed uniqueness of this minimum, too.  But, I didn't think that the Hessian from part I was relevant to Part II, which is this constrained optimization problem.  Is it indeed relevant, @MattSamuel?  Thanks,

Comment: No it's not as far as I know (I didn't notice there were constraints, that's why I deleted my comment). This is where my expertise ends without knowing the actual function. I'm an algebraist anyway, so don't despair.

Comment: Ah, ok no worries @MattSamuel - thanks so much for your quick response.  I will edit my question now to show the function and an assumption given in the problem statement, although I think the assumption was only relevant in the unconstrained optimization part of the problem.

Comment: There is a *different* Hessian that will help provided that's a reasonable point on the constraint set. You could restrict the function to the set and work in a coordinate chart and take the Hessian there. Sounds like overkill though.

Comment: That's almost a bilinear form. So I'm guessing $L$ is positive definite?

Comment: Hi @MattSamuel, yes L is positive-definite and also turned out to be exactly the Hessian of the function.  Is the answer now obvious and that I have overlooked something simple?  Thanks,

Comment: I don't know if it's obvious, but treating the quadratic terms as an inner product you could pick vectors with arbitrarily large "length" that will kill the sum of the components, hence you can make arbitrarily large positive numbers, so it has to be a minimum.

Comment: Provided the constraint set is unbounded!

Comment: Ahh...hmm... the constraint set is: $\large ∑_{j=1}^n A_{ij}u_j = g_i$ for i=1,2,…,m.  What do you think now @MattSamuel?  Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand that equation. Could you clarify?

Comment: Knowing $g_i$ exactly is very important here (also if that matrix is invertible this will be easier).

Comment: Sure @MattSamuel -- the equation gives m constraints.  Writing out all m constraints shows that the set of constraints can actually be rewritten as a linear system of constraints, so we can write it as a matrix equation, $A\vec u= \vec g$

Comment: Nope, no assumptions were given for this matrix, unfortunately @MattSamuel ...

Comment: Oh no problem then. An affine subspace with more than one point is automatically unbounded, so we're good.

Comment: Hmm...can you please elaborate on your last comment @MattSamuel?  Thanks,

Comment: The set $Au=0$ is a vector subspace, which is either a single point or unbounded (it's a line, a plane, a volume, etc). $Au=g$ is that subspace with $0$ shifted to $g$.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much for your time and patience @MattSamuel.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: No problem, you too.